# Sending automatically a Post request to a server from a Springboot application requiring a keystore

Tags: spring, rest, certificate

The application I develop must send a post request each time an event happen on a specific folder. 
I've built the JSON I want to post.

My issue is the following : the request must use a P12 certificate. For this I used :

```
keytool -importkeystore -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srckeystore MYCERTIFICATE.p12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype pkcs12
```

I set a yaml file which contains information about the keystore :

```
server:
  ssl:
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-store: 'classpath:keystore.jks'
    key-store-password: password
    key-alias: macsf_c
```

Finally I created a method that send the request to the remote server :

```
public DocumentDto sendRequest(DocumentDto documentDto) throws IOException {

    // set the URL to send the request
    URL url = new URL(properties.getProperty("signature.api.url.full"));
    // opening the connection
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

    // set protocol, accept & content type format
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    con.setDoOutput(true);

    System.out.println(con.toString());

    // create the JSON String
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    // for test purpose : generate the JSON file
    mapper.writeValue(new File("C:\\Users\\Dvera\\Documents\\testSignature\\document.json"), documentDto);
    // convert an oject to a json string
    String jsonInString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(documentDto);

    try(OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream()) {
        byte[] input = jsonInString.getBytes("utf-8");
        os.write(input, 0, input.length);
    }

    // read the response
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"))) {
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String responseLine = null;
        while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(responseLine.trim());
        }
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    }

    System.out.println(jsonInString);
    return null;
}
```

Actually i'm not working on the return type. My issue is that I have a 403 error. I do think that i must add the keystore to my request and i'm stuck at this point...

Comment: The `server.ssl` is for configuring SSL to use with SSL for the embedded tomcat NOT for making requests from the application.

Comment: I removed it but it doesn't change my issue

Comment: Ofcourse it won't change, as now you run your application without SSL (i.e plain http instead of https). I suggest to use a `RestTemplate`  and use the apache HTTP library to configure the SSL certificates to use.